# Replace a specific portion of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In a table named `my_table` I need to perform a find/replace on a specific string within the table content:

```
String to search for: 'http://123.456.789.000'

String to substitute: 'http://www.mysite.com'
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: If column string value comes `'http://123.456.789.000'` this clean, I doubt you would ask it as a question... Can you show us the exact string?

Comment: You added "within the table content" - where else would it be? It would be more helpful if you included the column name(s) and whether or not this string is contained within a larger string or if it is the whole column value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eek.

```
UPDATE dbo.my_table
  SET col = REPLACE(col, 'http://123.456.789.000', 'http://www.mysite.com')
  WHERE col LIKE '%http://123.456.789.000%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this easy?

```
UPDATE my_table
SET Field1 = 'http://www.mysite.com'
WHERE Field1 = 'http://123.456.789.000'
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hehe -- I like @Aaron's answer better if OP wants LIKE matches.  This would be better for exact ones.